# NEC code requirements for exterior outlet

Tags: receptacle, outdoor, nec

Are there any code requirements with regard to the position of an electrical receptacle on an exterior wall?  Such as distance above the ground, distance from a corner, distance down from a roof overhang.  Just wondering, don't want to put this in and find out I have to move it.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, there are

The Code cite you're after is NEC 210.52(E) (with subsections 1 and 3 being the commonly applicable ones):

> **(E) Outdoor Outlets.** Outdoor receptacle outlets shall be
>   installed in accordance with 210.52(E)(1) through (E)(3).
>
> Informational Note: See 210.8(A)(3).
>
> **(1) One-Family and Two-Family Dwellings.** For a one-family dwelling and each unit of a two-family dwelling that
>   is at grade level, at least one receptacle outlet readily accessible from grade and not more than 2.0 m (6 1/2 ft) above
>   grade level shall be installed at the front and back of the
>   dwelling.
>
> **(2) Multifamily Dwellings.** For each dwelling unit of a
>   multifamily dwelling where the dwelling unit is located at grade level and provided with individual exterior
>   entrance/egress, at least one receptacle outlet readily accessible from grade and not more than 2.0 m (6 1/2 ft) above grade level shall be installed.
>
> **(3) Balconies, Decks, and Porches.** Balconies, decks, and
>   porches that are attached to the dwelling unit and are accessible from inside the dwelling unit shall have at least
>   one receptacle outlet accessible from the balcony, deck, or
>   porch. The receptacle outlet shall not be located more than
>   2.0 m (6 1/2 ft) above the balcony, deck, or porch walking
>   surface.

In other words, there needs to be a readily accessible receptacle not more than 6.5' above the walking level in front, in back, and for each balcony, deck, or porch you have.

Comment: FYI - Even though it's not code. I have found that an exterior receptacle mounted on a wall needs to be at least 12" above grade or maybe up to 24" to avoid water from sprinklers and damage from lawn maintenance equipment. Sometimes use of good old fashion common sense and experience helps to make a better installation

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician -- yeah, Code doesn't capture everything :) (it's not a design manual, after all)

Comment: If you meet code you have attained the minimum!